# How do I reclaim the memory taken up by multiple TinyMCE instances?

Tags: tinymce

I used [this example](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/multiple_configs.php) on the TinyMCE website to dynamically create TinyMCE instances on a needed basis in my web application:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple",
        editor_selector : "mceSimple"
});

tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        editor_selector : "mceAdvanced"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
        <textarea name="content1" class="mceSimple" style="width:100%">
        </textarea>
        <textarea name="content2" class="mceAdvanced" style="width:100%">
        </textarea>
</form>
```

When the app does not need the editor any more, it removes it from the DOM. How do I reclaim the memory that the instance of the editor had taken up?